# succes function doesn't work in $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to get some data from an API through $.ajax i managed to get the response in my console so there is nothing wrong about the call, but the succes functiontion doesn't work , i tried even to put alert in the success function but still doesn't work .

```
    var symptoms = sessionStorage.getItem('resultSymptoms') ;
    var sendData =  {"patientID":{"ICD9":symptoms,
    "text_type":"long",
    "PatientName":"SomeName",
    "DoctorsName":"SomeName"}}

         $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "http://130.211.170.206:8080/freemium",
    contentType :"application/json",
    headers: {          
         Accept : "text/html"         
    }  ,
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(sendData),
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('This is the data '+data.text()) ;
          $('#resultTemplate').html(data.text()) ;
                },
      failure: function(data) {
         console.log(' failed to connect');
      }

});
});
```

EDIT :
when i put an error callback function i got parsing error

EDIT 2 : It is all fixed when i changed the datatype to 'text'

Comment: Its not calling success because, its throwing an error.
The way you wrote success callback, write one function for error callback and verify the error.
You're making request to cross domain, possibly you need to enable `CORS`.

Comment: Reading the doc is a good habit before you try : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: when i put an error callback function i got parsing error

Comment: it is not `.failure()`, according to the docs there is only a `.fail()` - method for catching errors

Comment: @ziz194: That probably means that the response isn't JSON, but an error message. Check the network traffic in the browser tools (F12) to see what the response was.

Comment: I changed the response in the API to just a text, and i can see it in the network traffic

Comment: You are may be getting error, that's why success function does not get called. And you write wrong ajax call syntax.. there is error: function () {} instead of  failure: function() {}

Comment: look at the update i've changed that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "http://130.211.170.206:8080/freemium",
    contentType :"application/json",
    headers: {          
         Accept : "text/html"         
    }  ,
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(sendData)
})
      .done(function(data) {
          console.log('This is the data '+data.text()) ;
          $('#resultTemplate').html(data.text());
      })
      .error(function(data) {
         console.log(' failed to connect');
      });
```

Comment: The `success` method is deprecated. Use the `done` method instead.

Comment: Why do you think that using the methods in the promise would work better than using the properties in the ajax settings?

Comment: @Guffa, this always works for me, so that's why I posted it in here :)

Comment: I'm not quitt sure if there is a method `.failure()`, I think it's `.fail()` instead [.fail()](api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/)

Comment: still doesn't work it says unexpected token '.' in the line of failure function

Comment: @empiric, i always use .error. But the OP uses .failure, so i thought that was good xD

Comment: @ziz194, post the response of the url. maybe there's something wrong there. Because this ajax call should be working. What's the error you're getting?

Comment: There is a comma too much after the `done` method. Also, if there is an `error` method in the `deferred` object then it is deprecated (the jQuery API docs is down at the moment). Use the `fail` method.

Comment: I fixed the comma problem but still got a parse error in the error callback function

Comment: What do you get when you put `alert(data);` in .error function?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `error` property to specify an error handler, that will allow you to see the error message:

```
var symptoms = sessionStorage.getItem('resultSymptoms');
var sendData = {
  "patientID": {
    "ICD9":symptoms,
    "text_type":"long",
    "PatientName":"SomeName",
    "DoctorsName":"SomeName"
  }
};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://130.211.170.206:8080/freemium",
  contentType :"application/json",
  headers: {          
    Accept : "text/html"         
  },
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify(sendData),
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('This is the data ' + data.text());
    $('#resultTemplate').html(data.text());
  },
  error: function(xhr, stat, err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + stat + ' ' + err);
  }
});
```